# Invalid conversion from 'const char**' to 'char* const*'

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm doing a school assignment where I have to call execvp, whose method signature is the following

```
execvp(const char* file, char* const argv[])
```

However my data is in the form:

```
std::vector<std::string*>
```

I've been trying to convert said vector into the right format for the second format of `execvp()`, but inevitably get the following error:

```
command.cc:120:29: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char**’ to ‘char* const*’ [-fpermissive]
     execvp(args[0], argv);
```

I've tried different variations but they all lead to this error. This error confuses me, since I have no idea what it means by `const*`. How can you have a `const*`? I'd consider changing the `std::vector` to some other type, but this is an assignment and I'm not really allowed to change it. Below is the code I use to try and create a `char*[]` from the vector:

```
    const size_t numArgs = _simpleCommands[i]->_arguments.size();
    std::vector<const char*> args;
    for(size_t j = 0; j < numArgs; ++j)
    {
        args.push_back(strPtrToCharPtr(_simpleCommands[i]->_arguments[i]));
    }
    const char** argv = new const char*[numArgs];
    for(size_t j = 0; j < numArgs; ++j)
    {
        argv[j] = args[j];
    }
    execvp(args[0], argv);
```

Comment: You keep writing `const char *` when in fact the function expects  `char *` (pointer to modifiable chars)

Comment: It would help to know what `strPtrToCharPtr(_simpleCommands[i]->_arguments[i])` returns. Please provide a [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `char* const argv[]` prototype means that `argv` is (the address of) an array of pointers to `char`, that the *pointers* in the array cannot be modified, but that the strings they point to can be.  This is different from a `char const **`, which is a pointer to a pointer to `char` *whose characters cannot be modified*.  Since passing it to a function that *might* modify the strings in the array would violate the `const` qualifier of `const char **`, it is not allowed.  (You could do it with `const_cast`, but that would be solving the wrong problem.)

Since `execvp()` is a very old UNIX function and would not have the same interface today, it doesn’t have any parameter to tell the OS how many arguments there are, nor does it promise not to modify the contents of the strings in the array.  You terminate the array by setting the final element to `NULL`.

It’s a similar format to the `argv` parameter of `main()`.  In fact, it becomes the `argv` parameter of the `main()` function of the program you run, if it was written in C.

This isn’t a complete solution, since this is a homework assignment and you want to solve it on your own, but you have to create that array yourself.  You can do this by creating a `std::vector<char *> argv( args.size() + 1 )`, setting each element but the last to the `.data()` pointer from the corresponding element of `args`, and setting the last element to `NULL`.  Then, pass `argv.data()` to `execvp()`.

Note that [the POSIX.1-2008 standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) says,

> The `argv[]` and `envp[]` arrays of pointers and the strings to which those arrays point shall not be modified by a call to one of the exec functions, except as a consequence of replacing the process image.

Therefore, you ought to be able to get away with casting away the `const`-ness of the strings in the array, this once, if you don’t mind living dangerously.  Normally, you would need to make a modifiable copy of each constant string in the array.

#### Update

Enough time has passed that I’m not giving out answers to homework.  A commenter claimed that my answer did not work on g++8, which means that they didn’t implement the same algorithm I was thinking of.  Therefore, posting the complete solution will be helpful.

This actually solves the closely-related problem of how to convert a `std::vector<std::string>` for use with `execvp()`.  (A `std::vector<std::string*>` is basically never correct, and certainly not here.  If you really, truly want one, change the type of `s` in the `for` loop and dereference.)

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE   700
// The next three lines are defensive coding:
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#define _XOPEN_VERSION  700
#define _XOPEN_UNIX     1

#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  const std::vector<std::string> cmdline{ "ls", "-al" };
  std::vector<const char*> argv;

  for ( const auto& s : cmdline ) {
    argv.push_back( s.data() );
  }
  argv.push_back(NULL);
  argv.shrink_to_fit();
  errno = 0;

 /* Casting away the const qualifier on the argument list to execvp() is safe
  * because POSIX specifies: "The argv[] [...] arrays of pointers and the
  * strings to which those arrays point shall not be modified by a call to
  * one of the exec functions[.]"
  */
  execvp( "/bin/ls", const_cast<char* const *>(argv.data()) );

  // If this line is reached, execvp() failed.
  perror("Error executing /bin/ls");
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Another twist on this would be to write a conversion function that returns the `std::vector<const char*>` containing the command-line arguments.  This is equally efficient, thanks to guaranteed copy elision.  I normally like to code using RIIA and static single assignments, so I find it more elegant to return an object whose lifetime is managed automatically. In this case, the elements of `argv` are weak references to the strings in `cmdline`, so `cmdline` must outlive `argv`.  Because we used C-style pointers as weak references, RIIA does not quite work here and we still need to pay attention to object lifetimes.

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE   700
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#define _XOPEN_VERSION  700
#define _XOPEN_UNIX     1

#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <vector>

std::vector<const char*> make_argv( std::vector<std::string>const& in )
{
  std::vector<const char*> out;
  out.reserve( in.size() + 1 );

  for ( const auto& s : in ) {
    out.push_back( s.data() );
  }
  out.push_back(NULL);
  out.shrink_to_fit();

  return out; // Benefits from guaranteed copy elision.
}

int main()
{
  const std::vector<std::string> cmdline{ "ls", "-al" };
  errno = 0;

 /* Casting away the const qualifier on the argument list to execvp() is safe
  * because POSIX specifies: "The argv[] [...] arrays of pointers and the
  * strings to which those arrays point shall not be modified by a call to
  * one of the exec functions[.]"
  */
  execvp( "/bin/ls", const_cast<char* const *>(make_argv(cmdline).data()) );

  // If this line is reached, execvp() failed.
  perror("Error executing /bin/ls");
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: The vector approach absolutely does not work on GCC 8.

Comment: @HunterZ I’ve now posted the code. I tested it on g++8, g++9 and clang++9 with `-std=c++11`.

Comment: Thanks. It turns out that the crucial piece is that, after all the work you had to do to build the vector, you still have to do a `const_cast` at the end. This makes the vector stuff almost a red herring in terms of dealing with `execvp()`, at least for my own related problem, and AndreyS' answer gets to the heart of it.

Comment: @HunterZ I could have passed in non-const data instead, but if they are initially in `std::string`, that requires a deep copy. A `const_cast` is the most efficient way around the fact that `execvp()` only takes a pointer to non-`const` strings for historical readons.

Comment: @HunterZ AndreyS’ answer is, I'm afraid, not correct. The relevant standard does say that the `exec()` family of functions cannot modify their strings.

Comment: I understand. In practical terms, however, what matters is what the compiler thinks and not what a standard says. As your own code demonstrates, there's no compilable way to take a const string and feed it to these APIs without either copying to an intermediate mutable buffer or casting away the const.

Comment: @HunterZ You’re correct that those are the two options. In this case, the latter is more efficient in both time and memory. There is a clean, safe way to do it with the STL that manages all the memory for you.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand the `std::vector<std::string *>` part (are you sure you don't need a `std::vector<std::string>`?), anyway...

Rule for `const`: it's applied to the element on the left; if there is non element on the left, it's applied to the element on the right.

So a `const char**` (or `char const **`, if you prefer) is a pointer to a pointer to a constant `char`. I mean: the constant part is the `char` pointed, not the pointers.

And `char * const *` is a pointer to a constant pointer to a `char`; in this case the constant part is one of the two pointers, not the `char` pointed.

In your case the function

```
execvp(const char* file, char* const argv[])
```

expect, as second parameter, a `char * const argv[]` (a C-style array of constant pointers to a `char`) that you can see as a `char * const *`.

But you call

```
execvp(args[0], argv);
```

where `argv` is a `char const **`, that is different to a `char * const *`.

So the error: the function expect to be able to modify the pointed `char`'s and you pass a pointer to a pointer to not modifiable `char`'s

And you can't define `argv` as a `char * const *`

```
char * cont * argv = new char * const [numArgs]; // <-- WRONG
```

because you can't modify it.

So, to solve the problem, I suppose you can define `argv` as a `char **`

```
char** argv = new char* [numArgs];

for(size_t j = 0; j < numArgs; ++j)
    argv[j] = args[j];

execvp(args[0], argv);
```

There ins't problem if you pass a not-constant object to a function that require a constant one (the contrary can be a problem), so you can pass a `char **` to a function that expect a `char * const *`.

Comment: This still doesn't work if you're trying to put a `const char*` into the array, such as you'd get from a `std::string::c_str()` call. It seems impossible to accomplish!

Answer (score 2):

1)  You don't need to have `const *` (const pointer) because pointer is automatically converted to const pointer if needed;

2) But you do need to supply `char*` (not `const char*` !) array as a second argument of execvp, i.e. your string characters should be modifiable. By having such a signature, execvp reserve its right to modify the supplied argument strings (yes it seems strange - but a process does have right to change its argument - note that `main()` routine may have (non-const) `char** argv` arguments!). Thus, you need to get rid of `const char*` in your piece of code and replace them by `char *`

Comment: This is the most helpful answer for me, because I am dealing with the case of a `const char*` being passed into a method that wrapped the process spawning process.

Comment: POSIX does in fact say that the `exec()` family of functions cannot modify their `argv` or `envp` strings. Therefore, the type signature is a historical legacy and you don’t need to make deep copies of the string data to work around it.